# An elementary probability theory problem

Tags: probability-theory, problem-solving, word-problem

I have just started learning probability theory and came across this problem,

> In each packet of Corn Flakes may be found a plastic bust of one of
>   the last five Vice-Chancellors of Cambridge University, the
>   probability that any given packet contains any specific
>   Vice-Chancellor being $\frac{1}{5}$, independently of all other
>   packets. Show that the probability that each of the last three
>   Vice-Chancellors is obtained in a bulk purchase of six packets is $1 - 3 \big(\frac{4}{5}\big)^6 +  3 \big(\frac{3}{5}\big)^6 -  \big(\frac{2}{5}\big)^6$

Now I understand how this is solved by considering each package as a seperate experiment and since their results (i.e which $V_i$ is inside) are independant, we have $p(V_1) = \big(\frac{1}{5}\big)^6$. Then we use the inclusion–exclusion principle.

However, I thought about it at first in a different way and I can't figure out why I am wrong. Our sample space $\Omega := \{\omega = (\omega^1,\ldots,\omega^6) : \omega^i  \in \{1,\ldots, 5 \}\}$ where each $\omega^{i}$ denotes the result of opening $i$-th package. Because getting each $V_i$ in each package is equally probable, the probability of getting any $\omega \in \Omega$ should also be $\frac{1}{|\Omega|}$. Now since for our problem *we don't care about the order* (which $V_i$ is in which package) and we are also allowed for instance to get an $\omega$ like $(1,1,1,1,1,1)$, the cardinality should be ${N+n-1\choose n}$ where $N = 5$ and $n = 6$. Let $A_i \subset \Omega$ contain all the sequence where figure $V_i$ appears at least once. Then $$\mathbb{P}(A_3 \cap A_4 \cap A_5) = \sum_{|A_3 \cap A_4 \cap A_5|} \frac{1}{210} = |A_3 \cap A_4 \cap A_5| \cdot \frac{1}{210}$$
I was stuck calculating $|A_3 \cap A_4 \cap A_5|$ but each time I tried, the answer was still wrong. So I don't think my approach is correct to begin with.

Any help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: Where can I buy those cornflakes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not care about the order, but the probabilities certainly do. Imagine that you toss a coin twice. Is the probability that you throw heads twice $\frac14$ or $\frac13$?

This is a question of how to apply (and how not to apply) the [principle of indifference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_indifference). The elementary equiprobable events here are the individual vice-chancellors being drawn in individual draws; so these are uniformly distributed. From this you can deduce by the [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) that their ordered tuples are also uniformly distributed. There’s no reason to believe that the unordered tuples are uniformly distributed.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm missing the lesson in 'You may not care about the order, but the probabilities certainly do'. Probability that you throw heads twice is indeed 1/4 since the tosses are independent right?

Comment: @ForumWhiner: Indeed. So it's the $4$ ordered tuples that are equiprobable, not the $3$ unordered tuples. The quip "You may not care about the order, but the probabilities certainly do." referred to "for our problem we don't care about the order" in the question. My point was that it doesn't matter what we care about (this is a misunderstanding that's often reinforced by imprecise talk about "distinguishable" and "indistinguishable" objects). That for independent trials ordered tuples are equiprobable and unordered ones aren't is due to the multiplication principle, not to what  we care about.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, make sense!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I understand the mistake in my thinking now.

Comment: The answer for the problem is apparently obtained from  $1-P(\cup_1^3 A_i)$ where $A_i$ is defined as the event you fail to obtain the ultimate, penultimate, and
ante-penultimate Vice-Chancellors. I don't understand the rationale for defining $A_i$ to be a failing event (at least that wouldn't be my first thought while approaching the problem). What is the way to approach the problem assuming $A_i$ is the event that I do obtain the i-th vice-chancellor? What is $\sum_1^3 P(Ai)$ in that case?

Comment: @ForumWhiner: That's a new question that goes in quite a different direction than the original question. A long comment under an answer is not the right place for such a question; please post it as a separate question. Feel free to ping me here in case you do so and would like me to take a look at it.