# Probability of obtaining the last three Vice-Chancellors in 6 packets of Corn Flakes

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am trying to solve the following exercise problem from "Probability and Random Processes" by Geoffrey Grimmett and David Stirzaker:

In each packet of Corn Flakes may be found a plastic bust of one of the last five Vice-Chancellors of Cambridge University, the probability that any given packet contains any specific Vice-Chancellor being $\frac{1}{5}$, independently of all other packets. Show that the probability that each of the last three Vice-Chancellors is obtained in a bulk purchase of six packets is $1 − 3(\frac{4}{5})^6 + 3(\frac{3}{5})^6 − (\frac{2}{5})^6$.

I understand from the solution booklet that the problem can be solved by symmetry, by taking 1− probability of NOT obtaining any of the last three Vice-Chancellors as: $1 - P(\cup_{i = 1}^{3} A_i)$ where $A_1, A_2, A_3$ are the respective probabilities of NOT obtaining the last, second last and the third last Vice-Chancellor.

They expand this using the inclusion-exclusion principle:

$1 - P(\cup_{i = 1}^{3} A_i) = 1 - 3P(A_1) + 3P(A_1 \cap A_2) - P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3)$

And this is equal to: $1 − 3(\frac{4}{5})^6 + 3(\frac{3}{5})^6 − (\frac{2}{5})^6$

If I am understanding correctly, $P(A_1)$ is $(\frac{4}{5})^6$ where any given packet in the six is guaranteed to yield a Vice-Chancellor, just not the last. And similar logic would apply to $A_2$ and $A_3$.

So my question is, why didn't they consider the cases where the said packet didn't yield any Vice-Chancellor. That means, I think $P(A_1)$ should be $(\frac{4}{5} + \frac{1}{5}(\frac{4}{5}))^6$ where the first $\frac{4}{5}$ is the probability of not obtaining any Vice-Chancellor and $\frac{1}{5}(\frac{4}{5})$ means obtaining a Vice-Chancellor, just not the last one.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

P.S. [An elementary probability theory problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3642573/an-elementary-probability-theory-problem) didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the chancellors be $A, B, C, D, E$. The alternating sum hints to principle of inclusion-exclusion (PIE), and subtraction from unity suggests calculating the probability of the complement - i.e., at least one of $C, D, E$ is *not* drawn. So, let's follow that approach.

The probability that no $C$ is drawn is $\left( \frac{4}{5} \right)^6$ - pretty straightforward. The probability that no $D$ is drawn is the same, and same for $E$. So, we have $3 \left( \frac{4}{5} \right)^6$ so far.

But we've overcounted, because the drawings in which *neither* $C$ nor $D$ are drawn (and also for the pairs $D$ and $E$, $E$ and $C$ - so $3$ in total) was counted twice in the previous calculation (make sure you see why). So to correct, we need to subtract the probability of these drawings: $3 \left( \frac{3}{5} \right)^6$.

Now we've undercounted, because the drawings in which none of $C, D, E$ are drawn were each counted $3$ times in the first and subtracted $3$ times in the second. We need to add the probability back to obtain the correct result: $\left( \frac{2}{5} \right)^6$.

Bringing it all together, we have $P = 1 - \left( 3 \left( \frac{4}{5} \right)^6 - 3 \left( \frac{3}{5} \right)^6 + \left( \frac{2}{5} \right)^6 \right)$, which is the desired result.

Comment: But what if neither A, B, C, D or E is drawn? It is given that the probability of any one of them being drawn at all is 1/5

Comment: "In each packet of Corn Flakes may be found a plastic bust of one of the last five Vice-Chancellors of Cambridge University, the probability that any given packet contains any specific Vice-Chancellor being $\frac{1}{5}$" - there is guaranteed a bust of some chancellor in each packet.

Comment: If it is guaranteed, I don't understand this: "the probability that any given packet contains any specific Vice-Chancellor being 1/5" Does it mean that obtaining any one of the 5 chancellors is equally probable??

Comment: It means $P (A) = P (B) = ... = P (E)$ (the probability any given packet contains any specific chancellor) are all equal to $\frac{1}{5}$.

Comment: Now I understand, thanks!